# How to stream images with correct number of pixels using camera app?

Tags: dart, flutter

When I stream Images using [camera app](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera)  . 
I con't convert YUV_420 to BGR. I hope lenU & lenV in below code should be 230400, if not, can you suggest me best way to convert [YUV_420](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#YUV_420_888) to BGR.

```
controller.startImageStream((CameraImage availableImage){
var framesY = availableImage.planes[0].bytes;
var framesU = availableImage.planes[1].bytes;
var framesV = availableImage.planes[2].bytes;
var lenU = framesU.length;
var lenV = framesV.length;
var lenY = framesY.length;
print('$lenU'+' '+'$lenV'+' '+'$lenY');
});
```

where, lenU = 460799 (I expect it should be 230400)

lenV = 460799 (I expect it should be 230400)

lenY = 921600